# How to remove or replace words in VIM

Tags: linux, vim, command-line, command

How can I replace or delete words in VIM anything after

```
m/PH
```

Is so hard to use `CTRL-v` to delete them because I have tons of similar name from last point

My word structure in **`vim`**:

[image: My word structure in vim]

Comment: Meaning for every line that contains m/PH delete everything after the capital H to the end of the line?

Comment: `:%s~\(m/PH\).*$~\1~g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the lines after the first occurence of `m/PH` then I would start a search from the first line to the first occurence and delete from this line on
`:1;/m\/PH/,$ d`
If you want to delete all characters in each line after `m/PH` then find this string, preserve it and "forget" anything else behind it
`:%s/\(m\/PH\).*$/\1`.

Comment: Super Thank Mr. I been looking for those answer nothing found on google .

Comment: Is there any way Mr. To that without inside VIM ? ,. My file name is `paragraph`

Comment: On Linux _sed_ can do it, the regular expressions (POSIX standard) are almost the same for _vi_ as for other tools.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your follow-up question

```
Is there any way Mr. To that without inside VIM ? ,. My file name is paragraph
```

if your file is named `paragraph`, the following `sed` command will do:

```
$ sed -i 's/\(m\/PH\).*/\1/' paragraph
```